# GHC 8.4.2 cannot import System.Random

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, random, ghc, symlink

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic Beaver", and I have a file named `BurgerKing.hs` which imports `System.Random` in the `random` package.

GHC 8.0.2, which is under Ubuntu's 'universe' repository, can compile it:

```
ndos@ndos-desktop:~/Haskell$ ghc BurgerKing.hs -O2
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( BurgerKing.hs, BurgerKing.o )

BurgerKing.hs:14:1: warning: [-Wtabs]
    Tab character found here, and in 171 further locations.
    Please use spaces instead.
Linking BurgerKing ...
```

But GHC 8.4.2, which is under Herbert V. Riedel's PPA and is linked via a symbolic link, fails to compile it:

```
ndos@ndos-desktop:~/Haskell$ ./bin/ghc BurgerKing.hs -O2
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( BurgerKing.hs, BurgerKing.o )

BurgerKing.hs:10:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
10 | import System.Random
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Why?

**EDIT:** I tried reinstalling the PPA, `ghc-8.4.2` and `cabal-install-2.2`, but the problem remains.

**EDIT 2:** I tried purging old versions of `ghc` and `cabal`, and then reinstalling `ghc-8.4.2` and `cabal-install-2.2` via `sudo apt-get install --reinstall`, but the problem remains.

Comment: Have you installed the `random` package since changing compilers?  They (8.0.2 and 8.4.2 or any pair of ghc compilers) don't share package databases.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson So I should do something with `cabal`? I tried `cabal install random --force-reinstalls` and the problem remains.

Comment: `cabal install random --force-reinstalls` this may be installing for your old compiler.

Comment: The short of it is you have a setup issue.  Your cabal is seeing a different compiler installation or package database than you are executing.  Whatever the issue, there isn't nearly enough information posted for someone to give you a sure-fire answer.  I suggest you uninstall all GHC's and reinstall.  Short of that, you could try diagnosing the issue, such as verifying versions of `ghc` and `ghc-pkg` but that requires some knowledge about how packages are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in somewhat ugly way. After I purged the old versions of `ghc` and `cabal`, I did these:

```
ndos@ndos-desktop:/usr/bin$ sudo ln -s /opt/ghc/bin/ghc
ndos@ndos-desktop:/usr/bin$ sudo ln -s /opt/ghc/bin/ghci
```

So `cabal` would locate `ghc`, and `random` package  could be downloaded successfully:

```
ndos@ndos-desktop:~/Haskell$ ./bin/cabal install random
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring random-1.1...
Building random-1.1...
Installed random-1.1
```

And `BurgerKing.hs` compiles well:

```
ndos@ndos-desktop:~/Haskell$ ghc BurgerKing.hs -O2
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( BurgerKing.hs, BurgerKing.o )

BurgerKing.hs:14:1: warning: [-Wtabs]
    Tab character found here, and in 171 further locations.
    Please use spaces instead.
   |
14 |         | Menu {price :: Int, name :: String, category :: MenuCategory}
   | ^^^^^^^^
Linking BurgerKing ...
```